# Tokenizer java (string)

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

For example, I`ve got Some string`a.b.c.d`, I have separated it by tokens. but now I want to do a specific thing with a, then something else with b, and something else with c. How can I do that?

```
String value="a.b.c.d";
StringTokenizer tokenize = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
while(tokenize.hasMoreTokens()){
    String separated1= tokenize.?????;  
    String separated2= tokenize.?????;                            
    String Val1 = someMethod1(separated1); 
    String Val2 = someMethod2(separated2); 
}
//tokenize next line is not solution
```

Comment: Why not use String.split()? StringTokenizer is a legacy class.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try with String.split()

Comment: it did not solve my problem, I can only choose how many of them I want to "print out ", but I still cant choose which one.

Comment: There is no law that says you have to use a loop. You can just use several `if` statements one after the other to check if there is still a token and get the next token and do something with it.

Comment: thanks @RealSkeptic,

Answer (score 3):

Just to spell out what @RealSkeptic already said, avoid the loop:

```
    String value = "a.b.c.d";
    String[] separated = value.split("\\.");
    if (separated.length >= 2) {
        String val1 = someMethod1(separated[0]); 
        String val2 = someMethod2(separated[1]); 
    } else {
        // other processing here
    }
```

You could do something similar with a `StringTokenizer` if you liked, only you would need at least two if statements to check whether there were enough tokens. But as @user3437460 said, `StringTokenizer` is now legacy; `String.split()` is recommended in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Using [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) you can split about the `.` into an array.

How about something like this which will print each token:

```
        String value = "a.b.c.d";
        String[] tokens = value.split("\\.");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
```

The `.` needs to be escaped as the `split` function takes a regexp and `.` is a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use split ? Easier to use and makes more sense here